# DOM and LINQ Difference

Tags: linq, dom, operations

DOM and LINQ both are in-memory pattern.

Apart from deferred execution,what is the difference between DOM and LINQ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation whatsoever between DOM and Linq... DOM is a structured, in-memory representation of a document (usually XML or HTML). Linq is a language feature that enables querying on all types of collections.

Perhaps you're referring to Linq to XML ? The Linq to XML is pretty similar to DOM, with a few differences. Have a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387021.aspx) for details